# How to calculate CPU time in elixir when multiple actors/processes are involved?

Tags: erlang, elixir

Let's say I have a function which does some work by spawning multiple processes. I want to compare CPU time vs real time taken by this function.

```
def test do

  prev_real = System.monotonic_time(:millisecond)

  # Code to complete some task
  # Spawn different processes & give each process some task
  # Receive result 
  # Finish task

  current_real = System.monotonic_time(:millisecond)
  diff_real = current_real - prev_real

  IO.puts "Real time " <> to_string(diff_real)

  IO.puts "CPU time ?????" 

end
```

How to calculate CPU time required by the given function? I am interested in calculating CPU time/Real time ratio.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just trying to profile your code rather than implement your own profiling framework I would recommend using already existing tools like:

- [`fprof`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/fprof.html) which will give you information about time spent in functions (real and own)
- [`percept`](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-8.1/lib/percept-0.9/doc/html/percept_ug.html) which will provide you information about which processes in your system ware working at any given time and on what
- [`xprof`](https://github.com/Appliscale/xprof) which is design to help you find which calls to your function will cause it to take more time (trigger inefficient branch of code).

They take advantage of both `erlang:trace` to figure out which function is being executed and for how long and `erlang:system_profile` with `runnable_procs` to determine which processes are currently running. You might start a function, hit a receive or be preemptive rescheduled and wait without doing any actual work. Combining those two might be complicated, and I would recommend using already existing tools before trying glue together your own.

You could also look into tools like [erlgrind](https://github.com/isacssouza/erlgrind) and [eflame](https://github.com/proger/eflame) if you are looking for more visual representations of your calls.